# WSO2 OAuth tokens are not cleaned up in the DB after expiry

Tags: sql-server, wso2

I'm using WSO2 IS (4.0.0) with RDBMS (SQLSERVER) datastore.
I can successfully get an access token by hitting the URL     `https://localhost:9443/oauth2endpoints/token` via CURL.

But the token still exists in the DB (IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN) even after it expires; any subsequent request to get a new token as the same user (after the token expires) results in an exception that basically says a unique constraint in the table is violated.

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: If I remember correctly this was a known issue. But is there any reason for your to stick into the IS older version 4.0.0 ? This issue is fixed in the later versions

Comment: That is awesome....I will try out v 4.1.1. Do you remember the JIRA ID for the issue?

Comment: I tried out version 4.1.0....I still see the same issue in that version as well. Here is the stack trace I see : [2013-05-28 14:41:17,795] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO} - Error saving Access Token :Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'CON_APP_KEY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN'. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'CON_APP_KEY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN'.